# Optimizing a "reposts" MySQL query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table of posts, a table of reposts, and a table representing "user following" status.

I want to do something like Twitter, where I show all the posts or reposts from followed users.

I want the post to appear the first time it occurs, such that if multiple users repost the post, it only appears the first time.

In order to speed up this query, I insert into the repost table whenever a post is created, such that a corresponding repost (from the author) is also created.

My schema looks something like this:

```
Table Post
id: INT
userId: INT
time: INT

Table Repost
id: INT
postId: INT
userId: INT
time: INT

Table users_following
userId: INT
followerId: INT
```

And my query looks like this.

```
SELECT sr.* FROM Repost sr
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(ir.time) min_time, ir.postId FROM Repost ir
    WHERE ir.userId IN (
        SELECT uf.userId FROM users_following uf WHERE
        ir.userId = uf.userId AND uf.followerId = 1
    )
    OR ir.userId = 1
    GROUP BY ir.postId
) rr ON rr.postId = sr.postId AND sr.time = rr.min_time
```

The idea is this:

1. **SELECT FROM users_following uf.** Select all the user ids followed by the viewer.
2. **SELECT FROM Repost ir.** Select the min repost time for a given post, where the reposter id is either a followed user or the viewer.
3. **SELECT FROM Repost sr.** Select the repost with the min time for a given post using inner join.

This works, but stage 3 is slow. I believe this is because once we have a big list of min_times, we can't use any indexes to select from that subquery, meaning we need to scan everything. Is there a way to structure this query to make it more performant?

Here's the full `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the hardcore readers.

**EXPLAIN**

```
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                               | key                  | key_len | ref                             | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                        | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL                            | 797455 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | sr         | NULL       | ref    | IDX_DA9843F3E094D20D,repost_time_idx,repost_stream_idx      | repost_time_idx      | 4       | rr.min_time                     |      1 |     4.92 | Using where              |
|  2 | DERIVED            | ir         | NULL       | index  | IDX_DA9843F364B64DCC,IDX_DA9843F3E094D20D,repost_stream_idx | IDX_DA9843F3E094D20D | 4       | NULL                            | 797456 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | uf         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,IDX_17C2F70264B64DCC,IDX_17C2F702F542AA03           | PRIMARY              | 8       | prose_2_24_2021.ir.userId,const |      1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
```

**SHOW CREATE TABLE Repost**

```
CREATE TABLE `Repost` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `postId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isRepost` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_DA9843F364B64DCC` (`userId`),
  KEY `IDX_DA9843F3E094D20D` (`postId`),
  KEY `repost_time_idx` (`time`),
  KEY `repost_stream_idx` (`time`,`userId`,`postId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DA9843F364B64DCC` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `ProseUser` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DA9843F3E094D20D` FOREIGN KEY (`postId`) REFERENCES `Post` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=809018 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**SHOW CREATE TABLE users_following**

```
CREATE TABLE `users_following` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `followerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`,`followerId`),
  KEY `IDX_17C2F70264B64DCC` (`userId`),
  KEY `IDX_17C2F702F542AA03` (`followerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_17C2F70264B64DCC` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `ProseUser` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_17C2F702F542AA03` FOREIGN KEY (`followerId`) REFERENCES `ProseUser` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**EDIT**

Adjusting the query like so yields much faster results, though adding the `ORDER BY` makes it slow. Without `ORDER BY`, this query is great.

```
SELECT sr.* FROM Repost sr
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(ir.time) min_time, ir.postId FROM Repost ir
    INNER JOIN users_following uf ON ir.userId = uf.userId AND uf.followerId = 1
    GROUP BY ir.postId
) rr ON rr.postId = sr.postId AND sr.time = rr.min_time
ORDER BY sr.time desc
LIMIT 10
```

Here's the explain for this query:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                  | key                  | key_len | ref                       | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                           | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL                      |  691 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | sr         | NULL       | ref    | IDX_DA9843F3E094D20D,repost_time_idx,repost_stream_idx,repost_stream2_idx      | repost_stream2_idx   | 8       | rr.min_time,rr.postId     |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | uf         | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,IDX_17C2F70264B64DCC,IDX_17C2F702F542AA03                              | IDX_17C2F702F542AA03 | 4       | const                     |  145 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ir         | NULL       | ref    | IDX_DA9843F364B64DCC,IDX_DA9843F3E094D20D,repost_stream_idx,repost_stream2_idx | IDX_DA9843F364B64DCC | 4       | prose_2_24_2021.uf.userId |    9 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | rp         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,post_spotlight_idx,post_time_idx,post_trending_idx                     | PRIMARY              | 4       | prose_2_24_2021.ir.postId |    1 |    50.00 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: To find out what's slow, try first to prepend `EXPLAIN EXTENDED ....` to your query.

Comment: WHERE .. IN must be convertied to JOIN. PS. It's interesting, how do you save repost of repost (which is a post of reposter!) on this structure...

Comment: EXPLAIN shows type `ALL` on `<derived>` table consisting of about 800k rows. Not great. :p

Comment: @Akina repost of repost is not supported. Just reposts of the original post. :)

Comment: @Akina yeah I experimented with that. I wasn't seeing a big improvement, though it makes sense that it'd be faster in theory. The slow part is the outer-most INNER JOIN (stage 3).

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE post` and paste the result into your question. Do the same thing with `repost` and `users_following` tables. That way we can see the full table schema including PK, indexes etc. And please post along your full `EXPLAIN` result.

Comment: @FaNo_FN Added them just now. I left out Post, since it's more for context, and not part of the actual query in question.

Comment: Some sample data and a desired result might be fun

Comment: @Akina I conoverted the WHERE .. IN to an INNER JOIN, which is much faster. Now the only issue is the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Remove keys `IDX_17C2F70264B64DCC` and `IDX_17C2F702F542AA03` but create index `users_following (followerId, userId)`. Also try to create ```Repost (`time`, postId)```.

Comment: It looks like the Edit lost the `OR ir.userId = 1` -- Maybe that is why it sped up; does it give the wrong answer now?

Answer (score 1):

The typical way I'd write such a ranking query is thus:

```
select id, postid, userid, time
from
(
  select rp.*, min(time) over (partition by postid) as first_time
  from repost rp
  where userid = 1 
  or userid in (select userid from users_following where followerid = 1)
) numbered
where time = first_time;
```

Sometimes optimizers have problems with `OR` and fail to see they can run through the table twice, if they consider this faster. In that case we can hint with `UNION`:

```
select id, postid, userid, time
from
(
  select rp.*, min(time) over (partition by postid) as first_time
  from
  (
    select *
    from repost
    where userid = 1 
    union all
    select *
    from repost
    where userid in (select userid from users_following where followerid = 1)
  ) rp
) numbered
where time = first_time;
```

Once MySQL was known for having trouble with `IN` clauses. I don't think that is the case anymore. If the DBMS does have problems, you can use `EXISTS` instead:

```
from repost rp
where exists 
(
  select null
  from users_following uf
  where uf.userid = rp.userid 
  and uf.followerid = 1
)
```

In MySQL versions prior to version 8 analytic functions like `MIN OVER` were not available. In these versions you'd have to find the minimum time per post and then read the table again. One straight-forward way:

```
select *
from repost
where (postid, time) in
(
  select postid, min(time)
  from repost
  where userid = 1 
  or userid in (select userid from users_following where followerid = 1)
  group by postid
);
```

In any case you want an index to look up followed users quickly. The DBMS is free to come with a repost user and check if they are followed by user #1 or to take user #1 and find all followed users. So I'd provide two indexes:

```
create index idx1 on users_following (userid, followerid);
create index idx2 on users_following (followerid, userid);
```

Then you want to find their reposts quickly, then group by post ID and order by time. The index for this:

```
create index idx3 on repost (userid, postid, time);
```

Another way to look at this: If we read through the whole table and keep the rows for the desired users, it would be great were the rows already sorted by postid, time. So, just in case:

```
create index idx3 on repost (postid, time);
```

for a full index scan.

Indexes are an offer to the DBMS. The DBMS can accept this offer and use the index or not. What I often do:

1. Think about in which order the DBMS may access the tables.
2. Provide indexes for those routes.
3. Use `EXPLAIN` to see which of my indexes get used.
4. Drop the others.

Comment: `OVER` needs 8.0 or 10.2; what version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Repost needs an overhaul of indexes from

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_DA9843F364B64DCC` (`userId`),
  KEY `IDX_DA9843F3E094D20D` (`postId`),
  KEY `repost_time_idx` (`time`),
  KEY `repost_stream_idx` (`time`,`userId`,`postId`),
```

to

```
  PRIMARY KEY(postId, userId, time, id),   -- `id` is for uniqueness
  INDEX(id)  -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

(I don't know if the others have any use.)

Change `IN ( SELECT ... )` to `EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )`

`OR` is a performance killer.  Time the query with one side of the OR, then with the other side.  Assuming the sum of those times is faster than your current time, `UNION` those together.  Simplify each of the queries if practical.  Show me the results; I may have more index suggestions.